# open react project in visual studio code by cmd

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm new to React. I created a new project in React in cmd. I'm in the project folder inside the cmd. And I want to open the project itself through visual studio, I want to do it through cmd - how can I do that?
I tried to write "c" when I'm in the project's folder in cmd - it's not working. I know to register c - works on mac - I use window - I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Try with ```code .```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't React problem. If you want to open VS Code in the current directory, just type `code .` in the command prompt.

Comment: For more options of VS Code command line interface, you can check out the official documentation here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line